# Improve performance when using GoJS

Tags: javascript, performance, gojs

I have to deal with very big data sources lately and was wondering if there was a way to increase the performance of GoJS.

GoJS is very efficiently processing my data, and the `TreeView` I am trying to make is displayed shortly after the site is fully loaded. Unfortunately, when panning the view, the diagram somehow begins to lag a little.

I am now looking for a way to decrease that lag to a minimum.

I tried fiddling with the Layout options but it did not result in significant performance increase.

To the diagram, I have a diagram with "relatively" few nodes (498 to be precise), but my template is unfortunately rather complicated. It has a nested itemArray, which generates rows and columns inside that row. Another thing is that I use a slightly modified version of the "LayeredTreeView" model.

These nodes are in 388 invisible groups. Generating it without using layout things like crossing reduction only takes a moderate amount of time.

Also i have just discovered the [performance](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/performance.html) site of the GoJS introduction. It has been mentioned there, that complex templates make GoJS slow. Could this here be the case?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: By the way, panning does not invalidate any layouts, so fiddling with layout options will not effect scrolling/panning/zooming performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will provide more detailed information using an edit.

Comment: I just tried modifying samples/treeView.html to create 20000 nodes.  Initializing the diagram took some time, but scrolling was about as fast as ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complicated templates take longer to build than simple ones, so the loading time will take longer when the nodes are complex and detailed.

However, once all of the Nodes and Links have been created and initialized in the Diagram, scrolling (a.k.a panning) should be pretty fast.

Virtualization decreases load time because there should be very few nodes and links to create and show initially.  However virtualization does slow down scrolling and zooming because nodes and links have to be created as the viewport changes.  And as that Performance page suggests, implementing virtualization requires a lot more programming work.  And it might not even be feasible or faster, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Hmm... Can you tell me which events could affect the panning negatively?

Comment: The total number of nodes and links does affect panning, but it really shouldn't be too noticeable.  As I said above, I modified the TreeView sample to have 20000 nodes (and 19999 links), and scrolling in desktop Firefox was still great.  That's with each node including a Picture, although it's the same image for all of the Pictures.

Comment: Also as the Performance page mentioned, transparency and gradient brushes can slow down drawing speed.  But that's not usually a noticeable problem either, except maybe on mobile devices.

Comment: Colors that are like "rgba(...,...,..., 0.2)".  Or setting http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#opacity to a value other than 1.0.

Comment: I mean, on which part of the node does transparency effect something?

Comment: Any use of a translucent Brush -- the more pixels, the slower it is. **BUT** I doubt this is your problem.

Comment: Okay. Does it also decrease performance to have fully transparent nodes? I mean nodes where no fill is set at the shapes?

Comment: I really recommend that you perform your own timing tests so that you can characterize the nature of any performance problems.

Comment: Thank you, that transparency thing solved my problem.